# mod_rewrite: redirect rule for a URL string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm totally lost when it comes to mod_rewrite and redirect rules and was wondering if anyone could help!!!

I need a rewrite rule that will strip off a specific 14 character alpha numeric string from the end of the URLs i.e. domain.com/blahblah/z1234567891011 (the string always starts with the same letter, then is followed by 13 numbers).

I also need a rewrite condition so the rule is only applied to urls that contain the string, as not all of the urls on the site have the same string.

Have spent quite a bit of time looking around at similar questions and testing on a simulator, but not finding anything that works so far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try up to now? So we can point where the problem is, instead of providing a complete solution (which will most people object to).

Comment: What are the rules to identify a string which should be removed? Is it always the same string, oder does it have to start with a certain character, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+/)z\d{13}/?$ $1 [NC,R,L]
```

Or if you also strip off the new final `/`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/z\d{13}/?$ $1 [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on check mark on top-left of my answer.